# IIS error 403.14

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8, http-error

I'm trying to set up an ASP.NET MVC 5 site on windows server 2012 r2 datacenter IIS. Request for the default page fails with error given below. What can be the reason?

By the way I have     *runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"* in web.config.

```
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 

ModuleName: DirectoryListingModule     
Notification: EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER     
HttpStatus: 403 
HttpReason: Forbidden     
HttpSubStatus: 14     
ErrorCode: The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to map URL to actions via routing,

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Otherwise, ASP.NET MVC will not process your URLs. In turn IIS thinks you are accessing a directory and triggers this error.